# Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException.The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST

Tags: php, laravel, routes

i've started learning laravel recently, working on this password reset api, but i've been dealing with this error whenever i clicked on the forgot password line on login page.

Here's the web.php:

```
    Route::get('/userPasswordChange', 'HomeController@changePassword')->name('userPasswordChange');
    Route::post('/userPasswordChange', 'HomeController@changePasswordStore')->name('change.password');
```

Here's the HomeController.php:

```
   public function changePassword(){
        return view('userPasswordChange');
    }
    public function changePasswordStore(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'current_password' => ['required', new MatchOldPassword],
            'new_password' => ['required'],
            'new_confirm_password' => ['same:new_password'],
        ]);
   
        User::find(auth()->user()->id)->update(['password'=> Hash::make($request->new_password)]);
   
        return redirect()->route('change.password')->with('success','Thay đổi mật khẩu thành công.');
    }
```

Here's the userPasswordChange.blade.php:

```
@extends('user.layouts.master')
@section('main-content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Đổi mật khẩu</div>
   
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('change.password') }}">
                        @csrf 
   
                         @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                            <p class="text-danger">{{ $error }}</p>
                         @endforeach 
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Mật khẩu hiện tại</label>
  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="current_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Mật khẩu mới</label>
  
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
  
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">Xác nhận mật khẩu mới</label>
    
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="new_confirm_password" type="password" class="form-control" name="new_confirm_password" autocomplete="current-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>
   
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    Cập nhật mật khẩu
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Thanks for the help!!

NOTE: i did try cache reset

Comment: Welcome to SO ... even though the URI of those routes looks the same, i would imagine the redirect in the controller should be going to the `GET` route not the `POST` route ... `userPasswordChange` ... if you do `php artisan route:list` do you see the `GET` and `POST` route for that URI in the list?

Answer (score 2):

You have the current route

```
Route::get('/userPasswordChange', 'HomeController@changePassword')->name('userPasswordChange');
Route::post('/userPasswordChange', 'HomeController@changePasswordStore')->name('change.password');
```

While in current method

```
public function changePasswordStore(Request $request)
{
    ...
    return redirect()->route('change.password')->with('success','Thay đổi mật khẩu thành công.');
}
```

As you can see in redirect, it is redirecting to the same POST route `change.password`. You should change it to your get route `userPasswordChange` if this is the intended route you wish to redirect. Else other GET route.

TLDR:

```
public function changePasswordStore(Request $request)
{
    ...
    return redirect()->route('userPasswordChange')->with('success','Thay đổi mật khẩu thành công.');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I messed it up when trying to find the fix, actually it was like you said. I did change as u you mentioned but nothing works

Comment: Can you post in your question the actual change you made based on my answer? Did you change the route name in your redirect like what I posted in my answer?